# Adding formula into textbox and print

Tags: c#, winforms

**Q:** How to get my converted value from the input of the textbox entered by the user into the second textbox?

I am not sure how to fix the logic error which I am making.

I am just converting the input into the new weight and put that value into the second textbox.

Here is the code I have so far.

```cs
namespace Your_weight_on_Saturn
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var earthWeight = float.Parse(earthBox.Text);

            // holds the formula to calculate and find the value.
            var solve = (earthWeight / 9.81) * 10.44;
            MessageBox.Show("Your weight on saturn is" + solve);
            this.convertButton.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
        }

        private void saturnBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Where you are initializing solve, just set the text of the other TextBox to Solve. Like this:

```
solve = (earthWeight / 9.81) * 10.44;
SecondTextBox.Text=solve.ToString();  // It will set text of Second TextBox to the value of solve
```

Comment: Why do we add the ToString(); method as well? Does it convert it back to the text and displays it onto the textbox as well even though solve is a float value? How would I be able to round my decimal points to 3 places as well?

Comment: Yes, .ToString() is converting it to string and setting the text of the destination textBox to that string. 
You can round your decimal place to three decimal places by using Decimal.Round(solve, 3);

Answer (score 0):

simply convert it to float

```
solve = (float) ((earthWeight / 9.81) * 10.44);
```

Comment: Okay! Thank you, this fixed my conversion value issue.

Comment: My issue now is, I want to print the value onto the second text box instead of a separate message box. The solve value will be stored in the output of the second box.

Comment: @FlashO   Emrah - answered your second question